# SQL Server Equivalent method for: sys_connect_by_path

Tags: sql-server, tree

My SQL Server query below fails on:

sys_connect_by_path(folder_names.name, '//') "PATH"

I believe it was created in Oracle.  Can someone help replace that bit of code with the 2016 SQL Server equivalent ?

```
select  -- report, package, 
       path
from (
    select report_names.name                            "REPORT"
    ,      sys_connect_by_path(folder_names.name, '//') "PATH"
    ,      package_names.name                           "PACKAGE"
    from cognos_cs.cmobjects folders
    join cognos_cs.cmobjnames folder_names on folders.cmid = folder_names.cmid and folder_names.isdefault = 1
    left join cognos_cs.cmobjects reports on folders.cmid = reports.pcmid and reports.classid = 10
    left join cognos_cs.cmobjnames report_names on reports.cmid = report_names.cmid and report_names.isdefault = 1
    left join cognos_cs.cmrefnoord1 packages on reports.cmid = packages.cmid and packages.propid = 31
    left join cognos_cs.cmobjnames package_names on packages.refcmid = package_names.cmid and package_names.isdefault = 1
    where folders.classid = 1 

    start with folders.cmid = 2
    connect by prior folders.cmid = folders.pcmid
) group by -- report, package,
              path
order by path
;
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. That fails because it is trying to call a function that doesn't that doesn't exist. You are going to have several other issues here because this just isn't even close to sql server syntax. I would honestly start a new query and figure out what you need returned.

Comment: Ok, will do, thank you.  I am  trying to extract a tree/path report for the Cognos folders\subfolders and field names.

Comment: For SQL Server you would use a Recursive Common Table Expression (CTE).  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017